# Android TextView + ImageView alignment works on tablet but not phone layout

Tags: android, android-imageview, textview

I have a weird issue where the text in one of my TextViews won't align properly with the ImageView beside it. The thing that's weird is that on tablets, there is no issue, but on phones the text does not center vertically. The xml for tablets and phones for this issue are exactly the same, I literally copied and pasted my tablet layout xml code into my phone layout xml:

```
<TextView
 android:id="@+id/newTaskTV"
 style="@style/blueTextMediumBold"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/newTaskIV"
 android:layout_alignTop="@+id/newTaskIV"
 android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/newTaskIV"
 android:background="@drawable/domacare_blue_button_selector"
 android:gravity="center_vertical"
 android:paddingLeft="15dp"
 android:paddingRight="15dp"
 android:text="@string/add_task"
 android:textColor="@color/white" />

<ImageView
 android:id="@+id/newTaskIV"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
 android:background="@drawable/blue_button_selector"
 android:padding="5dp"
 android:src="@drawable/ic_add_white" />
```

The result on tablet:

[image: tablet image]

The result on phone:

[image: phone image]

(The line underneath is a custom View, shouldn't be related since it is aligned below these two views.)

I tried wrapping them in a LinearLayout and that didn't change anything. For some reason the text does not want to go to the center no matter what. Even worse, Eclipse is teasing me since its preview of the layout is correct, but the final result is not.

[image: eclipse image]

Comment: What version of Android are you running your phone on?  I tried something similar to this and it looked just fine for me on ICS.

Comment: 4.3 Cyanogenmod. You might have something there, because on my emulator (2.3.3) it looks fine, and my tablet is on 4.1.2. I'll test this on an official 4.3 device tomorrow, and if it doesn't work, well... this is a really dumb thing to not be future-proof.

Comment: Yep, on my Nexus 7 (4.3) they all show up with gravity == top rather than center vertical. That is unfortunate.

Answer (score 0):

The `TextView` should be underneath the `ImageView`. As far as I knew, the `RelativeLayout` needed the views referred in attributes such as `android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/newTaskIV"` to be defined before (=above).

Obviously this is not true anymore since it works on your tablet so I'm wondering if it could come from an older OS version on your phone.

Answer (score 0):

Hey you can use text view with image if you don't want to handle event separately on both..

`<TextView
        android:id="@+id/newTaskTV"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/add_task"
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/image"
        android:drawablePadding="5dp"
        android:singleLine="true"/>`